# Why doesn't this delete the '&' from the end of the user command?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, strlen

I'm writing a basic shell in C, and I want it to be the case where if the entered command contains an &, then it will run in the background and the user can still execute other commands.

But for some reason, I can get the program to run in the background, so I know that the IF statement works (where it checks for the '&') but I can't get it to remove the '&' sign from the command.

Here is the relevant code, feel free to ask questions:

```
int main(void)
{
  Command cmd;
  int n;

  while (!done) {

    char *line;
    line = readline("> ");
//This should check if 'line' contains an &, and remove it if so.
    if (strchr(line, "&") != NULL) {
      line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
      char **cmds;
      cmds = separateCmd(line);

      if (!line) {
      /* Encountered EOF at top level */
        done = 1;
      } else {
        stripwhite(line);

        if(*line) {
          add_history(line);
          /* execute it */
          n = parse(line, &cmd);
          PrintCommand(n, &cmd);
          executeBgCmd(cmds);
        }
      }

        if(line) {
          free(line);
        }
    } else {
      char **cmds;
      cmds = separateCmd(line);

      if (!line) {
      /* Encountered EOF at top level */
        done = 1;
      } else {
        stripwhite(line);

        if(*line) {
          add_history(line);
          /* execute it */
          n = parse(line, &cmd);
          PrintCommand(n, &cmd);
          executeCmd(cmds);
        }
      }

      if(line) {
        free(line);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance :D

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us *in* the question itself.

Comment: By the way, you know that the pointer returned by the [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) function is a pointer to the character itself. What happens if, for example, the character `'&'` *isn't* the last on the line?

Comment: And ***listen to what the compiler is telling you!*** The messages is prints is quite relevant for your problem.

Comment: Lastly a generic tip: Don't copy-paste generic code to create duplicates of it. There's only a single line that differs between the two paths in the `if ... else ...`, try to extract it so you don't have the same code in two places.

Comment: So your REAL problem is removing a character from a string? Then you should focus on that and post a question about it if you cannot solve it. Since you have isolated the problem, there's no need to post the complete code for your shell. Just create a [mre] where you fail to remove a character from a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I compile your code and look at the warnings I see:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

So the compiler tells me that your code is wrong! Looking up `strchr` (e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html), I see that `strchr` expects the second argument to be the character to search for. But your code pass a string (or more precise: a pointer to the first character of a string):

```
if (strchr(line, "&") != NULL) {
                 ^^^
                 ups
```

Try this instead

```
if (strchr(line, '&') != NULL) {
```

From the man-page I can also see that `strchr` returns a pointer to the character if it's found. Therefore it could make sense to write the code like:

```
char* pHit = strchr(line, '&');
if (pHit != NULL) {
  *pHit = '\0';      // Terminate string at first &
}
```

so that the `&` doesn't have to be the last character.

A simple test program could be:

```
int main()
{
    char line[] = "hello & world";
    printf("Before: %s\n", line);
    char* pHit = strchr(line, '&');
    if (pHit != NULL) {
      *pHit = '\0';
    }
    printf("After: %s\n", line);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before: hello & world
After: hello
```